# Store JSON as CSV with Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, csv

Hi I'm absolutely new to php and want to store a json-object from javascript as a .csv file via php.

I have a JSON-Object, defined in a File called Logger.json:

```
{
    "Name": "Dummy",
    "Uhrzeit": "1234",
    "Speed": "100",
    "Level": "11",
    "Szenen": {

    }
}
```

After reading the file in via $.getJson, I add some properties to the object. Logger.php now receives the content (first it has always been empty, because i missed `json_decode($_POST['data'], true);` the boolean true at the end), but the stored .csv just contains ("Array, Array").

I've also tried other content-types, just sending the jsonText (without data=) or the object obj itself. Any ideas why it won't work? Thanks!

```
$.getJSON('xml/Logger.json', function(obj) {

        //add new scene:
        obj.Szenen["144"] = {};
        obj.Szenen["144"]["happy"] = {};
        obj.Szenen["144"]["happy"].type = "right";
        obj.Szenen["144"]["happy"].collected = "0";
        obj.Szenen["144"]["sad"] = {};
        obj.Szenen["144"]["sad"].type = "false";
        obj.Szenen["144"]["sad"].collected = "0";
        obj.Szenen["144"]["angry"] = {};
        obj.Szenen["144"]["angry"].type = "false";
        obj.Szenen["144"]["angry"].collected = "0";
        obj.Szenen["200"] = {};
        obj.Szenen["200"]["happy"] = {};
        obj.Szenen["200"]["happy"].type = "right";

        console.log(obj);

        var jsonText = JSON.stringify(obj);

        var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "http://localhost/logger.php")
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", true)


var data = "data="+jsonText;
request.send(data);
```

My logger.php looks like this:

```
<?php

 $values = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
 store($values);

function store($data) {
    $file = 'logs/UserLogging';

    $filename = $file."_".date("d-m-Y_H-i",time()).".csv";

    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
    foreach($data as $line){
        //$val = explode(",",$line);
        fputcsv($fp, $line);
    }    
    fclose($fp);    
}

?>
```

Edit:
The .csv should somehow look like this (but if the keys like "Name" or "Uhrzeit" would also appear in the output, it would be perfect) :

```
Dummy,1234,100,11;
144,happy,right,0,sad,false,0,angry,false,0;
200,happy,right ...
```

Comment: You haven't explained what you hope the final CSV to look like? This sounds like *make this advanced sub-dimensional property-value data into a line of text*.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to add a possible .csv output and how it should look like! But just some sort of structured output for further processing in Excel would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your [fputcsv syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) is incorrect -- argument 2 has to be an array (that gets exploded into comma-separated values).

For example, `fputcsv([a,b,c])` would write `a,b,c` to the file followed by a newline.

You just need to transform your JSON-decoded object into an array. Without knowing the format you want, here's a simple example:

...(in function `store`)...

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
fputcsv($fp, (array)$data);
fclose($fp);
```

That stores a CSV of the top level keys.

Comment: Thanks this helped for the first keys! I will have a closer look at fputcsv!

Comment: Did everything turn out okay? Feel free to accept my answer if so, or add additional info so I can help you to conclusion!